# SELECT the individual rows that make up the aggregate MAX per day

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, common-table-expression, window-functions

[My dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pyqkUjcU)

I have a table that stores user counts every 5 minutes for multiple devices. Each device has its own row per timestamp. As I show in my fiddle, I created a query to sum all of the rows per create_time for a particular day.  I then added to the query to find the max sum. I then added to find the create_time of the group that has that max sum. I then combined them all together to get the individual rows that make up the group for the create_time that had the max sum. Great!

While it works for a specific day, I just can't figure out how to do it for multiple days.  I thought I could throw some group by date(create_time)'s in there but I clearly am not grasping group by with having. From this point, I can't say I've tried anything else because I just can't wrap my brain around it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
I have added a query to the bottom of the fiddle that shows what I want my results to be. It's fine for a demo of "the last 3 days" but the options can go back 12 months and I don't think 365 UNIONS would be the way to go ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function to get for each day the value of each day's `create_time` with the greatest sum of `users`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(create_time) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(create_time) ORDER BY SUM(users) DESC) create_time 
  FROM test 
  GROUP BY create_time
)
SELECT id, create_time AS stat_time, users
FROM test
WHERE create_time IN (SELECT create_time FROM cte);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SXe0LiZg).

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?  this code groups the users sums by date only

```
select date(create_time) as date_create,
sum(users) as ut
from test
group by date_create;
```

Comment: No, it is much more complex than that.  For each day, I want to retrieve all of the rows that make up the group by create_time that results in the max sum for that day. I can do it for a single day (as shown in my fiddle link), but I can't do it for multiple days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that I completely understand your question. From what I understand you can run your query for each date in the database by using a procedure and cursors.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AggregateMaxPerDay()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE uniqueDate DATE;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT DATE(create_time) FROM test;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  OPEN cur;
 read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur INTO uniqueDate;
IF done THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT id, create_time AS stat_time, users
                    FROM test
                    WHERE create_time = (
                      SELECT create_time FROM (
                        SELECT create_time, SUM(users) AS ut
                        FROM test
                        WHERE DATE(create_time) = "', uniqueDate, '"
                        GROUP BY create_time
                      ) t2
                      WHERE t2.ut = (
                        SELECT MAX(t.ut) AS ut
                        FROM (
                          SELECT create_time, SUM(users) AS ut
                          FROM test
                          WHERE DATE(create_time) = "', uniqueDate, '"
                          GROUP BY create_time
                        ) t
                      )
                    );');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END LOOP;
 CLOSE cur;
END;


CALL AggregateMaxPerDay();
```

Comment: I added a query to the end of my fiddle to demonstrate what I'm looking for. All of the entries for the days I need to query.  I need to be able to do it for any number of days so a loop of individual day queries would be very expensive, I think.